# Azure Policy to Audit NSG rule sourceAddressPrefix

Tags: azure, azure-networking

In Azure I have an NSG Rule configured as follows:

[image]

Im trying to write an Azure Policy, to audit if the Source IP addresses/CIDR ranges is not set correctly.

The value should always be exactly equal to: 192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24.

If it is not that exact value, it should audit.

This is the definition I have written:

```
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
            },
            {
                "field": "name",
                "like": "jeffweb2-dr-sm-nsg"
            },
            {
                "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*]",
                    "where": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].name",
                                "equals": "SQL"
                            },
                            {
                                "anyof": [
                                    {
                                        "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].sourceAddressPrefix",
                                        "notEquals": [
                                            "192.168.0.0/24",
                                            "192.168.1.0/24"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "greater": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
    }
}
```

But when trying to create the definition with this json, I get the error:

```
New-AzPolicyDefinition : InvalidPolicyRule : Failed to parse policy rule: 'Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'notEquals'.'.
```

**Question:** How do you pass multiple CIDR ranges into the notEquals, I believe this is my problem I believe.

Answer (score 1):

sourceAddressPrefix only supports a single IP range, you want to use sourceAddressPrefixes.

The UI in the portal hides this, but they are two different properties in ARM.

Comment: Is the not equals value right being comma separated as it is still not working?

Comment: It wont let me pass in the array of CIDR's even when using sourceAddressPrefixes